# Check if User liked Facebook page or not

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the following Code, its a button to like a facebook page, and alerts: Thanks for the Like,
I was trying to check on page load to see if the user has already liked the page or not, and alert "Page already liked" or "Page is not liked yet".

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '637166706299573', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        alert('Thanks for the Like');
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="facebook.js"></script>
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/Tabyeed" layout="button_count" show-faces="true" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

I tried this but it didn't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function liked() {
    FB.api("me/likes/348028968575501", function(response) {
        if (response.data.length == 1) {
            alert("page liked already");
        } else {
            alert("page is NOT liked already");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Any help guys?
thanks

Comment: @zippyV , thanks for the edit, it looks much coder-friendly now :)

Comment: You're welcome. The character you used is for when you have `code` inline.

Comment: And for future questions what did you use ?

Comment: Select the code and click the { } button. It puts 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a login button/flow so best guess is that the `FB.api("me/likes/348028968575501"` will fail because the user isn't authenticated which is different from Event subscribe that doesn't rely on authentication.

Comment: Hello sir,
How can I change this to Event subscribe ? any example code ?

Comment: you cannot change me/likes to Event subscribe, /me/likes are for users that are authenticated.

Comment: and by authenticated you mean logged in or authorized the app ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been searching all over the place for a code that works. I guess there isn't.

Comment: The code works, you just need the user to authorize your app, if the code worked without authorization, it would be a breach of privacy.

Comment: How would I do that ?
Please give me an example code, I don't have a background with facebook apps. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for page tab application check like the page or not.

```
/**
 * get the signed request parameter and decode it to get the user's
 * 'liked' status for the current page
 */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
  $signedRequest = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
  list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2);
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}

/**
 * if the user has already 'liked' the page then render the 'liked' view
 * else, render the 'pre liked' view
 */
if (empty($data['page']['liked'])) {
  include 'views' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'pre_liked.php';
} else {
  include 'views' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'post_liked.php';
}
```

Create a new application as page tab and on index.php use this code